# How to create a spectra in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, interpolation, fits

So I have a directory with about 50 .fits files with spectral information about CO. Each file corresponds to one CO peak at a specific wavelength. I want to write a code that plots a wavelength range and then add the peaks from each of those fits files into the range to basically build the CO spectra at the chosen wavelength range. Do you guys and gals have any tips of how I would do this? I'm not really looking for a code from you, I'm just kind of new to Python and I'm not sure how to start this project. Hope the question is clear, let me know if you have further questions. Thanks!!

Comment: I don't think, that this is the right website for your question. This is for *explicit* programming questions, like "This is my code, I get the error xyz, I have tried this and that"

Comment: Anyways; generic approach would be: 1)Learn how to read a .fits file 2)Learn how to plot with Python (look into matplotlib) 3)Learn array handling (look into numpy) 4)if then you run into a specific problem, look here on stackoverflow for a solution 5)if you don't find one, make a new question

Comment: http://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/generated/examples/io/plot_fits-image.html

Comment: There's a brilliant free PDF book called "Think DSP" available here... http://greenteapress.com/thinkdsp/thinkdsp.pdf Note also that **ImageMagick** can read, and write, FITS images, so you can simply convert from FITS to something PIL/Pillow is happy with.

Comment: Thanks for the links! They were really helpful :)

Comment: Hi @Laura as has been noted StackOverflow is unfortunately not the place for this kind of broad support question, but I hope this doesn't discourage you.  The Astropy website lists a few resources you can start with for looking for help getting started with Python for astro research: http://www.astropy.org/help.html  I particularly recommend the Python in Astronomy FB group (I don't like the fact that it's on FB but it's still a helpful bunch).